# Removing Margins and Padding within Vuetify

Tags: vuetify.js

So I'm pretty much brand new to Vuetify and Front End development, so sorry if my question is either simple or maybe even too vague.

I'm trying to build a website with Nuxt and Vuetify, but I'm having an issue with removing the padding around the edges of the pages. I've tried using different components within Vuetify such as fluid, I've tried finding and altering the container css code (which I'm not even convinced I've actually found), I've tried just about anything I have found on Stack Overflow or on the Vuetify github, but nothing is working for me.

Does anyone have some advice on how to actually go about having the container take up the whole page instead of leaving margins and padding on the side? I've spent at least 5 hours over the past 2 days trying to figure this out. [This is what I currently have.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hi52h.jpg)

Comment: can you please share your code.

Comment: Post the css code you tried and preferably a minimal working example so that others can work on it.

Comment: class `fluid` on container should remove margins I think. But anyway - for removing all margins and paddings use classes: `ma-0 pa-0` https://vuetifyjs.com/en/layout/spacing#how-it-works

Answer (score 69, accepted):

use [spacing helpers](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/layout/spacing#how-it-works):

`class="ma-0"` removes margins
`class="pa-0"` removes padding
`class="ma-0 pa-0"` removes both

Note that these are also props but only for some (grid) components so for example:
`<v-text-field class="pa-0"></v-text-field>`  will work,
and `<v-text-field pa-0></v-text-field>` will not work.

If in some components you can't remove spacing with these classes, then you need to target relevant elements with CSS.

Comment: Great explanation. Just as a comment; for negative margin and padding, you can use `n` prefix. like `class="ma-n2 pa-n3"`

Answer (score 7):

Ok, so I was able to figure out what I was doing wrong.

Here

```html
<template>
  <v-app light> 
    <v-toolbar fixed app :clipped-left="clipped" color="deep-orange accent-3">
        <v-toolbar-side-icon @click="drawer = !drawer"></v-toolbar-side-icon>
    
        <v-toolbar-title v-text="title"></v-toolbar-title>
        <v-spacer></v-spacer>
    </v-toolbar>

    <v-content>
       <v-container >
            <nuxt/>
       </v-container>
    </v-content>


    <v-footer :fixed="fixed" app></v-footer>
  </v-app>
</template>
```

So, in my source, everything is laid out in the "default.vue" page, which is here. I was trying to alter the styling in the actual page, so like in index.vue. When I took a closer look at default.vue, I saw the v-container, which I hadn't noticed before (like I said, complete beginner, so this is all pretty new to me).
I was able to add

```html
<style>
  .container{
     max-width: 100vw;
     padding:0px;
  }
</style>
```

to default.vue, which corrected the issue I was dealing with. It really just came down to understanding the template in which I'm working with, and finding the correct place to override the CSS.

Answer (score 3):

To remove paddings from cols, you can add "no-gutters" atribute to v-row:

```html
<v-container fluid>
  <v-row no-gutters>
    <v-col>
      <!-- content -->
    </v-col>
  </v-row>
<v-container>
```

Answer (score 2):

They also have predefined spacing helpers, ie pa-0.
https://vuetifyjs.com/en/layout/spacing

Comment: This is a borderline [link-only answer](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/8231). You should expand your answer to include as much information here, and use the link only for reference.

Comment: Ouh yeah, I love it how SO always encourages people to break the "single source of truth" rule. Why would we want to have a duplicate of the docs here that no-one will ever update? A link is so much better. If it breaks, the information is most probably outdated anyway. But 5 years later it still works :-o OMG!

Answer (score 1):

One good way to handle these scenarios is to use a **fluid** `v-container` on your main **Nuxt** entry point like this (default layout):

```html
<template>
  <v-app>
    <v-main>
      <v-container fluid>
        <Nuxt /> <!-- Nuxt's entry point -->
      </v-container>
    </v-main>
  </v-app>
</template>
```

And now every time you need a full-width section set the container's `v-col` padding to zero (best is to use `pa-0` or `px-0` to be specific).

For example, inside my component I have:

```html
<template>
  <v-row class="image-background">
    <v-col class="pa-0">

      <v-container>
        <v-row>
          <v-col>
            <h2 class="text-h2">Some Text</h2>
          </v-col>
        </v-row>
      </v-container>

    </v-col>
  </v-row>
</template>

<style scoped>
.image-background {
  background-image: url("/images/your-image.jpg");
  background-size: cover;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: 50% 25%;
  min-height: 35vh;
}
</style>
```

To create a **full-width section** add `pa-0` class to it's column element (`v-col`).

class of `.image-background` simply adds an background image taking whole width of screen (since it is inside a `fluid` container with no padding on it's `v-col` parent).

Notice how I used another container (without `fluid` attribute) to hold it's content in a responsive manner including it's paddings and media query breakpoints.

I am using **Vuetify v2.6.1** and by the way if you're on a vanilla Vue environment this is the whole structure in one piece:

```html
<template>
  <v-app>
    <v-main>
      <v-container fluid>

        <v-row class="some-class">
          <v-col class="pa-0">
            <!-- everything below will take full-width -->
            <!-- unless inside another normal v-container -->
            <img src="/path/to/image">

            <!-- wrap other content inside another v-container -->
            <v-container>
              <v-row>
                <v-col>
                  <h2 class="text-h2">Some Text</h2>
                </v-col>
              </v-row>
            </v-container>

          </v-col>
        </v-row>

      </v-container>
    </v-main>
  </v-app>
</template>
```

Answer (score 0):

This is the way I used to do to remove the padding of radio/checkbox

class="ma-n8 pa-n8"/class="ma-0 pa-0" removes, add the negative and positive padding