# How to remove inside space from v-btn in Vuetify.js?

Tags: vue.js, vuetify.js

## Hi there! [SOLVED]

I'm trying to recreate a page using Vue.js and Vuetify, but I don't know how can I get the following result with my buttons:

This is my goal:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/umN4U.png

This is what I have now:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/rFwED.png

As you can see, I just need to remove the RED part inside the buttons, to make them stay smaller and together, as the following:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/Lr44Z.png

How can I remove this 'inside padding' from a v-btn?

This is my code:

```
<v-card>
  <v-flex xs12>
    <v-img src="https://cdn.vuetifyjs.com/images/parallax/material2.jpg"/>
  </v-flex>
  <v-card-text>
    {{ card.content }}
  </v-card-text>
  <v-card-actions>
    <v-btn small outline color="secondary" class="ma-0 text-capitalize">View</v-btn>
    <v-btn small outline color="secondary" class="ma-0 text-capitalize">Edit</v-btn>
  </v-card-actions>
</v-card>
```

Thanks yall!!

Comment: you remove padding with [`pa-0`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53373939/1981247). But seems like your problem is related to preset `min-width`, so set `min-width: 0`.

Comment: This `style="min-width: 0"` worked just fine! Thanks man!

Comment: Btw, practice here is to write answer in the answer section, not edit question with a solution. Question should only describe a problem. You can answer your own question, nothing wrong with it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Solving the problem

How to do it, thanks to [Traxo](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1981247/traxo).
Creating the following class it's enough:

```
<style scoped>
  .together{
    min-width: 0
  }
</style>
```

And then using it:

```
<v-btn small outline color="secondary" class="together ma-0 text-capitalize">Edit</v-btn>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Vue.directive('no-padding', {
  bind: (el, bindings) {
    el.style.padding = 0
  }
})

<v-btn small no-padding outline color="secondary" class="ma-0 text-capitalize">View</v-btn>
```

Comment: Vuetify utilizes `pa-0` class already, no need for directive. This approach seems weird, but anyway, OP's problem seem to be related to min-width. See my comment on the question.

Comment: Thanks for your help, I just needed `style="min-width: 0"` and now it's done. 
Thanks again!